# Only run javascript if php condition is met

Tags: php, javascript

I am attempting a simple test where javascript needs to run only if the `$checkpoint_date` is less than 7 days old.

```
<?php
$checkpoint_date = '15-08-2013';

if (strtotime($checkpoint_date) < strtotime('-7 day')){ 
?>

<script> alert('hi'); </script>

<?php } ?>
```

The `alert` appears to run regardless of the condition evaluating to true or not.

I know the above condition works because I've tested it:

```
if (strtotime($checkpoint_date) < strtotime('-7 day')){
    echo 'more than 7 days';
}else{
    echo 'less than 7 days';
}
```

Comment: It's working fine when I test it on phpfiddle. No alerts on `$checkpoint_date = '15-08-2013';` but showing up on `$checkpoint_date = '01-08-2013';`

Comment: you can do the date check in js.

Comment: @JmVerastigue: That's strange. I'm puzzled now.

Comment: @Dagon: I plan on populating `checkpoint_date` from the DB, which is why I am attempting this with PHP.

Comment: you can try using `echo` to see if that works. `echo("<script> alert('hi'); </script>");`

Comment: @JmVerastigue: It seems that if I try to echo the js, it does't execute, it prints it 'as-is' to the screen.

Comment: Ignore the echo stuff, your code is perfectly fine. Try changing `-7 day` to `-7 days`.

Comment: I think you got your logic backwards. If date is less than today minus 7 days (meaning it's over 7 days old), display the JS. Else, do nothing.

Comment: @JmVerastigue: Just wondering, which piece of code did you run in phpfiddle?

Comment: Same code. I just copied and pasted.

Comment: weirdly enough, After recreating the file and repasting the code it works..Thanks all for your input.

Comment: make sure you format your dates as `yyyy-mm-dd` to avoid a multitude of unexpected conflicts between US and European dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already tested this code. It should work just fine.

```
$today = date("d-m-Y");

$checkpoint_date = '15-08-2013';
if (strtotime($checkpoint_date) - strtotime($today) > 7){
    echo "<script>alert('More than 7 days')</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Less than 7 days')</script>";
}
```

second answer:

I try to test your code. it works fine actually. except that i use echo to output javascript.

```
$checkpoint_date = '15-08-2013';

if (strtotime($checkpoint_date) < strtotime('-7 day')){ 
    echo "<script>alert('less than');</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('more than');</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but this should do it:

```
<?php

    //last time 
    $checkpoint_date = '15-08-2013';

    if ( strtotime($checkpoint_date) < strtotime('-7 day') ) {
        $script = '<script> alert("hi"); </script>';
    }
    else {
        $script = '';
    }

    echo $script;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Get the contents of the pdf into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once('pdf.php');
    $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
            require_once($dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html); // Load the html
    $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF
    $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but maybe strtotime does not work with the format you are trying to pass it (15-08-2013).

Comment: It does according to the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)